# Groupby multiple columns & Sum - Create new column with added If Condition

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, pandas-groupby

I need to groupby multiple columns & then get Sum in a new column with added If condition. I tried the next code and it worked great with grouping by single column:

```
df['new column'] = (
    df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0).groupby(df['column1']).transform('sum')
)
```

However, when I try to group by multiple columns I get an error.

```
df['new_column'] = (
        df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0).groupby(df['column1', 'column2']).transform('sum')
    )
```

Error:

```
->return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key) 
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 
->indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key) 
->raise KeyError(key) from err 
->if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans: ('column1', 'column2')
```

Could you please advise how I should change the code to get the same result but grouping by multiple columns?

Thank you

Comment: provide a dataframe sample as a code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Cause of error

- The syntax to select multiple columns `df['column1', 'column2']` is wrong. This should be `df[['column1', 'column2']]`
- Even if you use `df[['column1', 'column2']]` for `groupby`, pandas will raise another error complaining that the grouper should be `one dimensional`. This is because `df[['column1', 'column2']]` returns a dataframe which is a two dimensional object.

##### How to fix the error?

###### Hard way:

Pass each of the grouping columns as one dimensional series to `groupby`

```
df['new_column'] = (
        df['value']
          .where(df['value'] > 0)
          .groupby([df['column1'], df['column2']]) # Notice the change
          .transform('sum')
)
```

###### Easy way:

First assign the masked column values to the target column, then do `groupby` + `transform` as you would normally do

```
df['new_column'] = df['value'].where(df['value'] > 0)
df['new_column'] = df.groupby(['column1', 'column2'])['new_column'].transform('sum')
```